# How to setup Travis CI for a Django project hosted on Heroku?

Tags: django, heroku, travis-ci

I'm trying to setup TravisCI on my Django project.

I'm using Heroku where a classic pattern is to use env var to get postgres database URL:

*settings.py*

```
DEBUG = (os.environ['DJ_DEBUG'] == 'True')
import dj_database_url
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)}
```

*example of .env file for my local env*

```
DJ_DEBUG=True
DATABASE_URL=postgres://root:captainroot@127.0.0.1:5432/captaincook
```

*Now, here is my .travis.yml conf file, that tries to use the locally created db*:

```
language: python

python:
  - 3.5

addons:
  - postgresql: "9.5"

before_install:
  - export DJ_DEBUG=False
  - export DABATASE_URL=postgres://postgres@localhost/travisdb

install:
  - pip install -r requirements.txt

before_script:
  - psql -c "CREATE DATABASE travisdb;" -U postgres
  - python captaincook/manage.py migrate --noinput

env:
  - DJANGO=1.9.10

script: python captaincook/manage.py test --keepdb
```

The project works everywhere, except when deployed on travis, where I got this Django error:
`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.`

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a typo: `DABATASE_URL` instead of `DATABASE_URL`.

But I suspect that rather than explicitly using export in `before_install`, you should use the [`env` key](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Defining-public-variables-in-.travis.yml):

```
env:
  - DJ_DEBUG=False
  - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres@localhost/travisdb
```

Comment: Thanks, the typo was the problem! About `env`, it works, but only where both variables are written on a single line, otherwise travis CI will create 2 builds, each with one env variable.

Comment: By the way, you were there 3 years ago when I started to learn Django, and still the first one to answer 3 years later :) You're crazy amazing :)

Comment: If you nest the environment variables under `global`, you can avoid matrix builds: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Global-Variables